# Convert Ascii into Text in Excel

Tags: excel, ascii

I have a file which has a structure as shown in the picture: 
[image]

I now have the problem that I need to have this data structured in an excel file which eventually should look like in the picture below:

[image]

I know that each file is in ASCII format and all the fields have a set length. For example from the first picture i know that the start position is 1 and the length is 2 and the field is record type. (as displayed in excel picture. Another example would be that I know that the field record counter starts at character position 34 and has a length of 10.

I am trying a way to "decode" the first picture into excel. 
Can anyone suggest a way of how to do this in excel or any other way.

Here is the picture of the fields and field length: 
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  What was the problem?  Your original file looks like an Excel file.  Is that really the case?  Or is it a text file with line numbers?

Comment: Also, your field starts and lengths don't match up with the pictures you have posted.  You will need to reconcile that before you can go further.

Comment: It is a text file and I want to convert it into excel so from picture 1 into picture 2. Furthermore the field length do match up. For example: Field "Record Type" starts from 1 and has length 2 which equals to "01" which is also shown in picture 2

Comment: @pnuts I am trying to find a tutorial for that now...
I found the following website for it: http://www.convertcsv.com/fixed-width-to-csv.htm

Comment: I must not be understanding the other field definitions.  For example, you show file type starting at location 3; but it seems to start at location 9; You extract a Financial Instrument SIA code which seems to start at location 3 and be of length 6 and that doesn't show up in your fields and field length table at all; etc.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ah okay, yes you are right, please ignore the field definitions here..the important bit here was only that I know the positions and length of the text which is the same in the excel. Apologies for that. Do you know a good way of "converting" that ?

Comment: What was the problem with @pnuts suggestion?